# Delete string element in array (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have a string: `pairs = ['AA';'AB';'BB';'AC'; 'CC'; 'CB';'DE'; 'BC']`

How can I delete the element which has the same characters in its string like 'AA','BB', 'CC' ?

The expected output should be: `out = ['AB';'AC';'CB';'DE';'BC']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logical indexing and compare first and second column:

```
out = pairs(pairs(:,1)~=pairs(:,2),:)
```

For a more general way (to cover rows with more than two characters) you can create the index of rows that have all elements equal to each other using bsxfun:

```
allsame = any(~bsxfun(@eq, pairs, pairs(:,1)), 2);
out = pairs(allsame,:);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the entries are only 2 elements, you could subtract each elements and if the result is 0 then both elements are the same.

Example:

```
pairs = {'AA';'AB';'BB';'AC'; 'CC'; 'CB';'DE'; 'BC'}

Diffs = cellfun(@(x) diff(x),pairs)
```

`Diffs` looks like this:

```
Diffs =

     0
     1
     0
     2
     0
    -1
     1
     1
```

Now delete those entries:

```
pairs(~Diffs) = []

pairs = 

    'AB'
    'AC'
    'CB'
    'DE'
    'BC'
```

Comment: Note though that the question had `pairs` as an array of strings. Instead of defining a new cell array as you have done, you could simply convert from the string array to a cell array, as `pairs = cellstr(pairs);`